# Sinnvoll sein - Sinn haben - Sinn machen

Tags: word-usage

Als ich noch zur Schule ging, bzw. auch als ich noch studierte (bis ca. 1990), taten wir Dinge, die *sinnlos* waren und andere Dinge, die *sinnvoll* waren.

Am Samstag mit Freunden ins Kino zu gehen, das hatte *Sinn* und war daher auch *sinnvoll*.
Bei einem bestimmen Lehrer um eine bessere Note zu flehen war hingegen *sinnlos* weil aussichtslos.

Manchmal war uns auch langweilig und wir kamen auf dumme Ideen. Wir spielten anderen Leuten Streiche und taten viele andere Dinge, die bei genauerer Betrachtung keinen *Sinn* hatten: Wir machten *Unsinn*.

Immer waren es Menschen, die *Unsinn machten*. Nie hat jemals ein Gegenstand *Unsinn gemacht*. Das wäre auch *unsinnig*, denn um *Unsinn* zu *machen* muss man aktiv eine Aktion setzen. Das können Gegenstände nur in den seltensten Fällen.

Und da das Gegenteil von *Unsinn* ja der ersten Eingebung nach *Sinn* sein müsste, kann *Sinn* ja - wenn überhaupt - eigentlich auch nur von Menschen gemacht werden. Aber die Sache hat einen Haken: *Sinn* kann nicht *gemacht* werden!

"*Macht keinen Unsinn!*" War eine Aufforderung, die oft zu hören war. "*Macht Sinn!*" hat uns niemals jemand zugerufen, und das hätte auch keiner von uns oder von irgend jemand sonst erwartet.

---

Heute, rund 20 Jahre später, *machen* plötzlich alle möglichen Dinge *Sinn*. Habe ich da was verpasst? Ist hier englische Grammatik plötzlich 1:1 ins Deutsche übernommen worden? Wenn es im Englischen heißt "It makes sence", wieso übersetzt man da nur die Vokabeln, nicht jedoch auch die Grammatik? "It makes sence" heißt auf Deutsch "Es ist sinnvoll". Zur Not geht auch noch "Es hat Sinn". Aber Sinn *MACHEN*? Ist das sinnvoll?

Und noch eine andere Frage habe ich, die in dieselbe Kerbe schlägt: Seit wann kann man in der deutschen Sprache man nicht nur Briefe und Pakete, sondern auch Fragen und sogar Probleme adressieren? "How does the government address the problem of unemployment?" heißt auf Deutsch nicht (wie ich leider schon mal auf einer Präsentationsfolie lesen musste): "Wie adressiert die Regierung das Problem der Arbeitslosigkeit?", sondern: "Wie geht die Regierung mit dem Problem der Arbeitlosigkeit um?". Und Fragen werden auch nicht adressiert, sondern gestellt.

Also: Macht es Sinn, diese Fragen an euch zu adressieren? Oder wäre es vielleicht sinnvoller, euch diese Fragen zu stellen?

---

### EDIT - NACHTRAG:

Ich kenne den Zwiebelfisch und weiß, dass "Sinn machen" den offiziellen Regeln widerspricht. Aber was ist nun falsch? Ist es falsch "Sinn machen" zu sagen, oder ist die Regel überholt und daher falsch?

Comment: Dir ist wohl der Zwiebelfisch entgangen. Sorry, aber das Thema ist schon tausendfach diskutiert worden und ich kann es schon fast nicht mehr hören. Ich sage selbst gelegentlich auch *Sinn machen*, obwohl ich mir dessen Inkorrektheit bewusst bin. Sei's drum. Es ist schon längst akzeptabel, und ein Kampf dagegen zwecklos.

Comment: Hier der [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-stop-making-sense-a-261738.html). Es gibt zu dem Thema auch noch ein - ich nenne es mal so - *[Anti-Zwiebelfisch](http://www.iaas.uni-bremen.de/sprachblog/2007/10/01/sinnesfreuden-i/index.html)*

Comment: Bzgl. Edit: Naja, wenn es den offizielen Regeln widerspricht, dann ist es auch falsch. Wenn es trotzdem jeder macht und geduldet wird, ist es akzeptabel. Ein Fußballer darf auch nicht am Trikot ziehen, solange der Schiedsrichter nicht pfeift, oder es einfach nicht sieht, ist es auch OK.

Comment: Aber lebende Sprachen ändern sich. Das heißt: Die Regeln ändern sich. Aber wann? Kennst du jemanden, der den vollkommen korrekten und regelkonformen Satz "Wenn es schön wäre ginge ich spazieren" sagen würde? Jeder würde sagen: "Wenn es schön wäre würde ich spazieren gehen." Und statt "Jeder würde sagen" sollte es korrekterweise sogar "Jeder sagte" heißen. Aber der Konjunktiv ist gerade dabei auszusterben. Es gibt ihn fast nur noch in der Theorie, also in alten und überholten Regeln.

Comment: Ich finde diese ganze Diskussion ziemlich sinnlos.

Comment: Danke an Em1 für den Anti Zwiebelfisch... das zu lesen hat echt Spaß ergeben

Comment: "Jeder" ist ein Allquantor und wird bereits durch einen einzigen Fall widerlegt - daher gilt es meist sparsam damit umzugehen. Mir geht es gar nicht so selten so, dass ich der Möglichkeit des Konjunktivs gewahr werde und auch mündlich diesen verwende. Mit "schön" und "spazieren" wird das villeicht nicht passieren, aber mit analogen Sätzen schon. Anderer Einwand: Die Frage arbeitet die Gemeinsamkeit von "Sinn machen" und "adressieren" nicht heraus (neumodisches Zeuch/Anglizismen). Entweder das sollte geschehen und eine abstrakte oder 2 konkrete Fragen sollten gestellt werden.

Comment: Der Schwerpunkt der Frage liegt aber da, wo die Überschrift hinweist. Mir ist der Grund zu schließen nicht hinreichend klar. Als beantwortbare Frage identifiziere ich, ob man "macht Sinn" schreiben darf, und ob man es schreiben soll. Es gibt etablierte Phrasen die unschön sind, aber toleriert werden, während andere ebenfallst etabliert, aber falsch sind (''optimalst''). Oder geht es um den Zwiebelfisch? In anderen SE-Foren ist es Usus, dass man den Inhalt fremder Quellen an Ort u. Stelle wiederholt, denn das Internet vergisst doch, und SE soll die primäre Quelle werden.

Comment: @userunknown Ich sehe das Problem ganz klar darin, dass das Thema schon - wie erwähnt - tausendfach diskutiert worden ist. Nun ist OP der Meinung, dass man das Thema wieder aufgreifen könnte, da sich evnt. inzw. was an den Regeln geändert hat. Mag auch prinzipiell richtig sein, der Duden listet tatsächlich machen als Umgangssprache. Aber - mal abgesehen von ein paar persönlichen Meinungen - werden wir hier nichts Weltbewegendes erzählen, eben weil das Thema schon so durchgekaut wurde. *Sinn machen* ist ganz offensichtlich aus dem Englischen übernommen, es ist im Standarddeutsch falsch, aber ..

Comment: ... wird Umgangssprachlich weitesgehend angewandt und akzeptiert. Lustigerweise hat gestern Abend mein Chef auch noch *Sinn machen* zu mir gesagt. Ich hab darüber schmunzeln müssen, aber habe nichts weiter gesagt. Warum auch. Es tat nichts zur Sache. - Wie auch immer. Die Intention der Frage ist schon mir schon bewusst, sonst hätte OP ja auch nur einen Einzeiler geschrieben und nicht so einen ausführlichen Dialog, jedoch hilft es nicht weiter, erneut darüber zu debatieren.

Comment: Außerdem sind die Sachen heute noch genau so *sinnlos* oder *sinnvoll*. Das Problem mit ist ja nicht, dass *sinnlos* oder *sinnvoll* ersetzt werden, auch *Unsinn* existiert noch. Problem ist ja, dass das *ergibt* verdrängt wird. Sprich, die Frage ist sowieso insofern nicht richtig gestellt, da *sinnvoll* immer noch oben ist, während nur die Sinnlosigkeit leicht abnahm. Siehe [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sinn+machen%2CSinn+ergeben%2CUnsinn+machen%2Csinnvoll+sein%2Cist+sinnvoll%2Csinnlos+sein%2Cist+sinnlos&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3)

Comment: Und noch ein [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sinn+ergeben%2C+Sinn+machen%2C+Sinn+haben%2C+ergibt+Sinn%2C+macht+Sinn%2C+hat+Sinn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3) zum Vergleich der Verben bei Sinn

Comment: a) Nun, es ist **hier** noch nicht diskutiert worden, oder man würde einen Link setzen. Wie oft etwas andernorts diskutiert wurde ... - ich lese nicht regelmäßig Sick. b) Dem Uni-Bremen-Blog kann ich auch einiges abgewinnen. c) Als Folge d. radikalen Konstruktivismus könnte die Akzeptanz d. "Sinn machens" jüngst zugenommen haben. d) Off topic: Interessant wie im ngram-diagramm der Nationalsozialismus eine Art Sinusschwingung durch das "Sinn ergeben" auslöst. Könnte Basis einer waghalsigen Theorie werden. :)

Comment: Auch hier kann ein Videotutorial auf [Belles Lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/sinn-machen-make-sense-anglizismus.php) empfohlen werden. Fazit: Die Aversion kommt nicht von ungefähr. Sowohl 'make', als auch 'sense' überschneiden sich nicht so sonderlich mit 'machen' und 'Sinn'. Die wörtliche Übersetzung d. einzelnen Wörter ist daher nicht angezeigt.

Comment: Das Übel begann schon ca. 1980 laut ngram. Der Osten blieb noch weitere 10 Jahre davon verschont. Erstaunlicherweise gibt es keinen Knick im Anstieg um das Jahr 1989.

Comment: Linguistik ist ein blöder Job. Gestern noch war was falsch, und nur weil es genug Leute falsch machen, ist es plötzlich richtig. ;)

Comment: [Link zu allen 5 Blog-Postings des ehemaligen "Bremer Sprachblogs" zu "Sinnesfreuden"](http://www.sprachlog.de/?s=sinnesfreuden); und [archive.org-Link zum 1. Posting von 2007](http://web.archive.org/web/20180312134428/http://www.iaas.uni-bremen.de/sprachblog/2007/10/01/sinnesfreuden-i/index.html)