# How to translate "to make no sense"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage

How would you say "to make no sense" in German? I've seen uses with *machen* and *haben*:

> Das macht keinen Sinn.
>
> Es hat keinen Sinn, mit Ihnen zu streiten.

Answer (score 15):

First, “Sinn haben” and “Sinn machen” (but more to the latter below) have different meanings:

> Es hat keinen Sinn, dies zu versuchen.

means that something is futile, *ein sinnloses Unterfangen*.

When we come to the expressions which are closer to the English “to make sense” we open a can of worms. The nearest proper German expression is “Sinn ergeben”.

> Dieser Text ergibt keinen Sinn.

There is also the expression “Sinn machen” with more or less the same meaning. This is probably a relatively recent (meaning I remember encountering it in the 1980s, but that might say more about my own age) anglicism, and as such is fervently hated by some. However, I think that the German „Sinn ergeben“ does not mean exactly the same as the English „make sense“ (I would need some time to collect my thoughts on this), so maybe there is a place for „Sinn machen“ in the German language. Pragmatically, it cannot be stopped anyway.

You might be interested in [this discussion of the subject](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/sinn-machen-make-sense-anglizismus.php), in which it is argued that “Sinn machen” does not make sense in German, because the possible meanings of “Sinn” and “machen” differ from those of “sense” and “to make”.

Comment: But "Sinn haben" is much more common than "Sinn ergeben", right?

Comment: @LuisSep True. And *Sinn machen* is most common.

Comment: “Sinn haben” und “Sinn ergeben” have different meanings, I'll clarify this.

Comment: @Em1 While many people (sometimes including myself) say *es macht keinen Sinn*, the correct term is *es ergibt keinen Sinn* (it doesn't make sense). The other term, *es hat keinen Sinn*, would translate to *there's no point in [...]*. http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-stop-making-sense-a-261738.html

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I wasn't responding to what is the correct term but to what is common. And *Sinn machen* is clearly what people say. I rarely encounter *Sinn ergeben*. (And actually in a couple of years *machen* in German will be considered as correct, too)

Comment: @Em1 Yes, a real shame.

Comment: In casual language, even `Sinn haben` und `Sinn machen` are merged in meaning.

Answer (score 3):

## Sense

> - Das ist sinnvoll.
> - Das ergibt einen Sinn.
> - Das hat einen Sinn.
>
> *Rather not so common*
>
> - Ich sehe einen Sinn darin.
> - Dahinter steckt/verbirgt sich Sinn.
> - Ich kann Sinn darin erkennen.

## No sense

> - Das ist sinnlos.
> - Es hat keinen Sinn.
> - Es ergibt nicht den geringsten Sinn.
> - Darin liegt kein Sinn.
> - Das scheint/bleibt ohne Sinn.
> - Mir vermag sich der Sinn nicht zu erschließen.
>
> *Rather not so common*
>
> - Das ist [absolut] ohne Sinn.
> - Der Sinn des Ganzen ist unergründbar.
> - Ich vermag den Sinn nicht zu ergründen/zu erhaschen/zu begreifen.

<sub>all phrases are from [here](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-stop-making-sense-a-261738.html) as cited by em1 [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4958/sinnvoll-sein-sinn-haben-sinn-machen)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think in Yiddish we can say "Das stimmt nischt". Does that work in German?

We also have "Das liegt sich nischt auf'n *seykhel*" with the Hebrew term. Literally that's probably close to "it doesn't stand to reason".

Comment: As always it depends on context and I think in most cases it won't work in German. At least if Yiddish "Das stimmt nischt" equals German "Das stimmt nicht".

Comment: I've checked some examples and it seems to be used in Yiddish very much in the sense of "it doesn't make sense"; or alternately, "that doesn't jive (with the facts)". And the German usage is different how?

Comment: As said, context is missing. The point is that "Das stimmt nicht" is rather "Das ist gelogen", "Das ist nicht wahr" but saying "That doesn't make sense" sounds more like "Das kann ich kaum/nicht glauben", "Da sind noch Widersprüche" or "Das klingt schlicht unlogisch" but is not necessarily a statement saying that something is not true. Then you would go in English with "That's not true" which is "Das stimmt nicht".

Comment: If we consider Yiddish as a "German language", and I very much do so, then it is interesting indeed if there are subtle differences in the meaning of *"das stimmt nicht"*.

Comment: If the German usage is close to "bullshit", it's quite different from the Yiddish. Here is an example in context from what we call "Yeshivish", the Yiddish-laced English spoken among the American ultra-orthodox: "As an aside, when I related this to the Rosh Yeshivah, he smiled. Ever the Talmudist, he replied, “Very nice, but shtimt nisht, not consistent with the the Gemara in Kiddushin [33B], which says a sefer Torah is on a higher level than a talmid chacham.”

Comment: And if used in the sense of "doesn't jive", it would actually be "einstimmen", as in "das stimmt nischt ein mit..."

Answer (score -1):

"Das macht Sinn" is a sentence coming from the English language. "Das hat Sinn" is an older, but also more correct German.

Here's a german article about them: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-stop-making-sense-a-261738.html

Comment: Hm - yes, but all that has already been said by others. Even the link was already provided, although just in a comment. -1 from me because I don't see anything new here.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that.