# How to understand the phrase “auf dieses Leben”?

Tags: phrase, idiomaticity

Ich habe diesen Satz in Deutschland gehört:

> Auf dieses Leben.

Kann man das so alleine verwenden?

I have heard this term in German. Does it make sense when it stands alone? It seems to translate only to *to this life.* I cannot include much context information, because it was simply said by someone at random.

Comment: Hi Anna, welcome to German.Stackexchange! You don't have to answer in German. Questions in English are perfectly fine. I corrected your German text (based on your English text) and wrote it as I would say it as native German. The translation of "make sense" is not so easy in German (see: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8132/how-to-translate-to-make-no-sense?lq=1). "Sinn machen" is an anglicism, which is often used in German since a few years....

Comment: Also feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.

Comment: Das macht nur Sinn wenn an eine Wiedergeburt glaubt oder ein zweites, ewiges Leben, und davon ausgeht, dass es der Angesprochene auch glaubt. :) Oder im Urlaub vielleicht, wo man es sich gut gehen lässt, während man sonst gestresst ist, _diese Form von Leben_ meinend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Auf dieses Leben* is a line of the song *Auf uns* by Andreas Bourani from 2014:

> Ein Hoch auf uns
>
> Auf dieses Leben

*Auf dieses Leben* is also a toast and with the song it became even more popular. Its meaning is more or less: Enjoy your life now (e.g. by celebration and drinking alcohol together), because we only live once.

So yes, as a toast *Auf dieses Leben* can stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

Ja, macht auf jeden Fall Sinn.

Zum Beispiel, wenn man mit jemandem anstößt. Dann sagt man sowas wie:

> Auf unsere Zukunft.

oder

> Auf uns.

oder eben auch

> Auf dieses Leben.

Comment: Macht Sinn... argh....

Answer (score 1):

The German expression 'auf *something*' can be a short form of 'ein Hoch auf …' meaning to cheer for or toast to something. Most common is perhaps 'auf uns' in the meaning of '(a toast) to us'.

The current usage of the phrase 'auf dieses Leben' has probably been influenced by the text of Andreas Bourani's hit 'Auf uns' used as a promotional song for the soccer world championship 2014, in which the refrain starts with 'Ein Hoch auf uns, auf dieses Leben, …' roughly translated 'Cheers to us, to this life, …'.

Answer (score 1):

The expression might be derived from the Jewish toast "l'chaim" as it is relatively uncommon in German but a standard phrase in Jewish.

Comment: Yiddish or Hebrew?

Comment: Urban dictionary says Jewish/Yiddish: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=l%27chaim

Comment: *l'chaim* is both Hebrew and Yvrit (modern day Hebrew). Yiddish took the phrase from Hebrew. Yiddish is the English spelling of Jiddisch, which stems from Jüdisch, which in turn just means Jewish.